# Why is a company like Bauer allowed to sell Wet/Dry vacuums without the three prong plug for safety?

Tags: grounding

Why is a company like Bauer allowed to sell Wet/Dry vacuums without the three prong plug for safety? I thought that all electrical appliances designed for outdoor and wet area use should have a third prong ground on the plug and be connected to a ground fault circuit interrupter (GFCI) receptacle!

Comment: There is a safety concept called "double insulation." Double insulated appliances do not need the GND wire. NOTE: GFCI outlets provide meaningful protection regardless of whether the attached device has a GND wire or not. The name of the manufacturer has no bearing on it. So perhaps you could remove "Bauer" from the question title.

Comment: https://www.grainnet.com/enewsletter/SafetyTipofWeek_SafetyAlert_3_20_17.html

Comment: Depends on legislation but in most parts of the world you are not required to have that so plain old double insulated appliances are used.

Comment: Very interesting question that I had myself a few weeks ago!

Answer (score 10):

The ground receptacle is only required when the outside of the appliance is metal.

When it is plastic and sufficient measures have been taken to make the device safe it is no longer required. See [class II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes#Class_II).

Ground is not required for the GFCI to work, if you throw your class II corded drill into a pool the GFCI will trip.

Comment: For reference, see 2020 NEC 250.114 "Equipment Connected by Cord and Plug"